# Correct indentation

Tags: vim, indentation

I had a HTML file with correct indentation. I deleted the `<html>` tags and `<head>...</head>`. My file is now indented too in the right and I'd like to shift everything to the left (about four spaces).

I tried the `gg=G` command without success

I tried it in visual mode by pressing `V`, selecting everyline, pressing `I`, deleting four spaces and pressing `ESC` - without success.

Is there some trick that can shift the indentation to the left?

thank you

Comment: quick'n'dirty: `s/^\t//`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `<G` in the command mode.

Comment: This helped the indentation but the tags that should be nested are on the same level.

Answer (score 2):

Select the lines, then press:

`<`

For more info:

`:help shift-left-right`

You could also use `CTRL-V` to enter block mode select, then delete the columns you don't want. You can also use `CTRL-V` to select a column then use `<` or `>` to indent/unindent only text to the *right* of that column (that can be very handy).

Comment: ...or if you are in insert-mode, you can use ctrl+d and ctrl+t to (d)ecrease and increase indent, no need to go to cmd-mode

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow.  Is it still an html file?  If not, then just give the filename a different extension (e.g., '.txt') and reopen it.  Then you can adjust indents however you want without the automatic html indenting being a problem.